# Abort application loading when exception in ServletContextListener

Tags: jakarta-ee

Is there a container independent way to abort application loading process when something fail in `ServletContextListener#contextInitialized`

If there are more than one application was deployed on that server, other applications should not be affected.

why does java ee not specify a standard way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can throw an unchecked exception in your listener. From the spec:

> > Some exceptions do not occur under the call stack of another component in the application. An example of this is a SessionListener that receives a notification that a session has timed out and throws an unhandled exception, or of a **ServletContextListener that throws an unhandled exception during a notification of servlet context initialization, or of a ServletRequestListener that throws an unhandled exception during a notification of the initialization or the destruction of the request object. In this case, the Developer has no opportunity to handle the exception**.
> >
> > **The container may respond to all subsequent requests to the Web application with an HTTP status code 500 to indicate an application error.** Developers wishing normal processing to occur after a listener generates an exception must handle their own exceptions within the notification methods.

What this means is that if you were to throw, say, an `UnsupportedOperationException` from your listener (or any listener really), you could effectively stop the application from being put into service. The container will always respond with an HTTP-500 (to which you can map an error page)

Answer (score -1):

Catch Exceptions in ServletContextListener, set them as Context Attribute, and throw ServletException in Servlet.init() if present (in all Servlets).